# Java JPA: Best practice for rollout of desktop app with DB?

Tags: java, database, jpa, versioning

I just wanna ask for best practices about rollout of java desktop apps including an embedded DB (like JavaDB).

**1. Question:**

I create version 1.0 of my app with an embedded JavaDB for rollout. Should I deliver the DB files within my rollout package or should the app create the embedded DB files by first start?

**2. Question:**

Now it's time for release 1.1 and the DB structure changed. How to deliver the update? Is there any best practive for release strategies?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do whatever is easier for you. Personaly I think beeing able to create a new DB on the fly is more conventient for developers.
2. You need an update script. If this happens more than once, put the version number 1.0, 1.1, ... into the db. This way you can check what update scripts have to run automatically and you can make sure your software and db do match.